# How to sort datatable alphabitecal and case insensitive using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

I am using jquery datatable. 
It display list of user.(first name, last name, etc). Is it possible  to set so that capital letter always comes before small letter when I click on ascending order of last name.(Case sensitive)

Following is example

```
FirstName   LastName
A             Xb   <--X is Captial-->
B             xa   <-- x is small-->
c             yc
```

When I click on sorting on last name with ascending order it will display following

```
 FirstName   LastName

B             xa   <--small-->
A             Xb   <--X is Captial-->
c             yc
```

Is it any property available which sort in case sensitive?

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem:

```
'columnDefs': [

 'targets': 0,      
 'render': function(data, type, row, meta){                                                     
  return type === "sort" ? data.toLowerCase() : data;

}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

```
var names = [
    {"FirstName":"A", "LastName":"Xb"},
    {"FirstName":"B", "LastName":"xa"},
    {"FirstName":"C", "LastName":"yc"}
];

names.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.LastName.toLowerCase().localeCompare(
        b.LastName.toLowerCase()
    );
});

console.log(names);
```

​

[See it working on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Hbnq/1/)
    ​

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try something like this:-

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['string-case-asc']  = function(x,y) {
return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0));
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['string-case-desc'] = function(x,y) {
return ((x < y) ?  1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
};
```

> Sorting performance has been improved by preparing the data to be
>   sorted before doing the sort itself. For example, it is pointless
>   doing .toLowerCase() on the same string multiple times - it will
>   always result in the same result. As such sorting functions may now
>   have a {type}-pre method as well as the {type}-desc and {type}-asc
>   methods to prepare the data. All the internal sorting methods now use
>   this method.

From the [source](http://datatables.net/new/1.9)

Comment: What is X and Y value? Which value they represnt?

Comment: They are the variables which I have taken . You can change it as per your reqm!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you say jquery datatable, you mean the datatable plugin at [Datatables.net](http://datatables.net).  If so, it looks like starting with version 1.9, case-sensitive sorting became available:

[bCaseInsensitive](http://datatables.net/docs/DataTables/1.9.beta.1/DataTable.models.oSearch.html#bCaseInsensitive_details)

Comment: I ma using jquery 1.4.4 version.

Answer (score 0):

The default sort type in datatables plugin is case insensitive. However, if you are using server side processing with SQL the case sensitivity comes from the database not from jquery.dataTables.js.  To get it fixed, find your SQL Query Order Clause and change it to lower().

If you are using the example provided here: http://www.datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql
Then, replace rows 81 & 82 with the code below and you are done.

```
$sOrder .= 'upper('.$aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ].")
".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] ) .", ";
```

Hope that helps.